# Attempting to find inactive users with a SQL query, returning too many rows

Tags: sql

I've got the following relationship:

> User <-- 1:many --> Playlists <-- 1:many --> PlaylistItems

When a new User is created they are automatically given one, empty playlist.

I am attempting to select all Users which have only 1 playlist AND that playlist must be empty.

Here's what I've got:

```
SELECT * FROM Users u 
JOIN Playlists p ON UserId = u.Id
WHERE (0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PlaylistItems WHERE PlaylistId = p.Id) AND (1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Playlists WHERE UserId = u.Id)))
```

This is returning too many Users. Some of them definitely have playlists with 1+ items in them, but I don't see the error in my SQL.

Alright, I went with Gordon Linoff's solution and here's how it looks when I use it as a delete:

```
DELETE from Users 
Where Id in (
    Select u.id
    FROM users u join
         playlists pl
         on u.id = pl.UserId left outer join
         playlistitems pli
         on pli.PlaylistId = pl.id
    GROUP BY u.id
    HAVING count(pl.id) = 1 and
           count(pli.id) = 0
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think of this as some joins and an aggregation.  You can use a `having` clause for your conditions:

```
select u.*
from users u join
     playlists pl
     on u.id = pl.UserId left outer join
     playlistitems pli
     on pli.PlayListId = pl.id
group by u.id
having count(pl.id) = 1 and
       count(pli.id) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to return the same number of rows as my solution, but I like the readability of this one more. :)

Comment: @SeanAnderson . . . I don't see how this can be returning users that have more than one item in a playlist.  If you have sample data, can you set up a SQL Fiddle with it?

Comment: I don't believe your solution is incorrect. I think there's just a larger than expected number of inactive users in my database. :) I'll accept your answer when time has passed.